# Form builder close icon issue using Formio

Tags: angular, formio

I am using Form builder in my application where when I drag a new element a popup appear with the properties related to that element,what the issue is in that popup close icon is not showing instead of that close icon related key (D7) is showing and the close functionality also working fine.

Can anyone let me know what the issue is...I don't have any clue as I googled it and doesn't found any solution

By the way,I'm using Bootstrap CSS in my application,I think bootstrap icons are overriding the form build icons but not sure.

[image]

Here are the styles:

```
 "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "src/assets/styles/app.scss",],
```

and the formio version I'm using is **"angular-formio": "3.17.0",**

Comment: can't you override using your css?

Comment: Sorry to say this...But I was unable to can you suggest me something to override the styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a typo from formio missing a `\` and not any font issues. You can override it like below.

```
.formio-dialog-close:before {
   content: '\D7' !important;
 }
```

**OR**

```
.formio-dialog.formio-dialog-theme-default .formio-dialog-close:before
{
   content: 'X' !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you,I think this is the default property of formio  right...and I've tried but no change.do I need to apply this class manually to any html tag??

Comment: You will have to include either of the solutions in your app stylesheet. If you are into modifying formio source code, then you can edit there are rebuild it. Thnaks!

Comment: Thank you...It.s working but a small change .It's working only when we mention the entire class